# Function auto mute in alsamixer is used for what?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, alsa, libalsa

I'm now writing a program (c and c++) using alsamixer on ubuntu. But I have a problem that sometimes my alsamixer goes back to mute. I think the reason is the function **auto mute** of alsamixer. But I do not know what function auto mute of alsamixer is used for what ? and when "auto mute" occurs?
I think maybe my program has made some activities that make "auto mute" occurred.

Comment: [acer - Alsamixer: howto disable auto-mute mode - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131857/alsamixer-howto-disable-auto-mute-mode) and [How to disable Auto-Mute Mode? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/431079/how-to-disable-auto-mute-mode) may shed some light on it. Triggered when you, e.g. plug-in headphones, etc..

Comment: Alsamixer just shows the controls of the hardware. How auto mute is implemented depends on your hardware.

Comment: in my program, i only use ALSA to get and set volume off device and i do not use anything related "auto mute". But when i search in google, i found that sometimes when i plug in a new device, this will active "auto mute" function. I am not sure about this. I have disabled "auto mute" and now i am continue checking the problem. I think maybe diasble "auto mute" will resolve my problem but i want to know how "auto mute" work to control the problem